GLFW Window is invisible
I am trying to create a Window with GLFW:
#include <iostream>
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

void errorCallback(int error, const char* description);

int main() {

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);

    std::cout << "Creating window ..." << std::endl;
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow* window;
    if (window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "CardGame", nullptr, nullptr); !window) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}

void errorCallback(int error, const char* description) {
    std::cerr << "Error: " << description << std::endl;
}

...but it is invisible.
The program doesn't print any errors and the window is getting created, it's visible in the Application Bar on KDE but the actual window doesn't show.
I am on Linux (Endeavour OS with KDE Plasma 6).
Edit: I have the latest GLFW version, the current master branch included as a Git submodule

You might need to swap buffers before the window becomes visible. Add glfwSwapBuffers(window); in your render loop, just before glfwPollEvents();
